# cakephp form with 3 models

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

i work on cakephp (v2) and i want to create a form in relation with 3 tables :

tasks--1,n--1,1--quiz_questions--1,n--1,1--quiz_answers

model task :

```
class Task extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Task';
    public $hasMany = 'QuizQuestion';

    public $_schema = array(
        'type' => array(
            'type' => 'tinyint'
        ),
        'level' => array(
            'type' => 'tinyint'
        ),
        'date_availability' => array(
            'type' => 'timestamp'
        ),
        'date_end_availability' => array(
            'type' => 'timestamp'
        ),
        'date_accomplishment' => array(
            'type' => 'timestamp'
        ),
        'title' => array(
            'type' => 'string'
        ),
         'description' => array(
            'type' => 'string'
        )
    );

    public $validate = array(
        'type' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'required'   => true,
                'allowEmpty' => false,
            )
        ), ..............etc

    );
```

model QuizQuestion :

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class QuizQuestion extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'QuizQuestion';
    public $hasMany = 'QuizAnswer';
    public $belongsTo = 'Task';

    public $_schema = array(
        'title' => array(
            'type' => 'string'
        )
    );

      etc..
}
?>
```

model QuizAnswer

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

    class QuizAnswer extends AppModel {
        public $name = 'QuizAnswer';
        public $belongsTo = 'QuizQuestion' ;

        public $_schema = array(
            'title' => array(
                'type' => 'string'
            )
        );
          ...etc....
    }
    ?>
```

TasksController home()

```
  public function home() {
            if ($this->request->is('post')) {
                $this->Task->create(false);              

                $this->Task->set($this->request->data);

                $valid = $this->Task->validates();

                /*debug($this->Task);
                exit();*/

                if ($valid) {

                        $r = $this->Task->saveAll($this->request->data['Task']);
                        debug($this->request->data['Task']);
                        if (!$r) {
                            $this->Session->setFlash(
                                    __('INTERNAL_ERROR (%s)', __LINE__), 'flash_error');
                        } else {
                            $this->Session->setFlash(
                                    __('Mission enregistré.'), 'flash_success');

                            $this->redirect(array(
                                'controller' => 'tasks',
                                'action' => 'home'
                            ));
                        }
                }
 else {
                             $this->Session->setFlash( __('pas bon'), 'flash_error');    


 }
            }
    }
```

and the form :

```
    echo $this->Form->create('Task', $formOptions);
    ?>

    <fieldset>
        <?php

        /*** ETC ***/


        $formLabel['text'] = __('Titre du Quizz');
        echo $this->Form->input('title', array(
            'label' => $formLabel,
            'class' => 'input-xxlarge'
        ));





        $formLabel['text'] = __('Libelle question %u');
            echo $this->Form->input('Task.QuizQuestion.0.title', array(
                'label' => $formLabel,
                'class' => 'input-xxlarge '
            ));
            $formLabel['text'] = __(('0') . ' - ');
            echo $this->Form->input('Task.QuizQuestion.0.QuizAnswer.0.title', array(
                'label' => $formLabel,
                'class' => 'span8'
            ));
        ?>
    </fieldset>





    <div class="form-actions">
<?php
echo $this->Form->button(
        '<i class="icon-white icon-ok"></i> ' .
        __('Publier'), array(
    'escape' => false,
    'class' => 'btn btn-success',
    'div' => null
        )
);
?>
    </div>
        <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

'title' and 'Task.QuizQuestion.0.title' are inserted into the db but 'Task.QuizQuestion.0.QuizAnswer.0.title' doesn't .

debug($this->request->data['Task']);

```
array(
    'type' => '1',
    'level' => '1',
    'date_availability' => array(
        'day' => '17',
        'month' => '08',
        'year' => '2012',
        'hour' => '00',
        'min' => '00'
    ),
    'date_end_availability' => array(
        'day' => '18',
        'month' => '08',
        'year' => '2012',
        'hour' => '00',
        'min' => '00'
    ),
    'date_accomplishment' => array(
        'day' => '18',
        'month' => '08',
        'year' => '2012',
        'hour' => '00',
        'min' => '00'
    ),
    'title' => 'ju',
    'description' => 'ji',
    'QuizQuestion' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'title' => 'jo',
            'QuizAnswer' => array(
                (int) 0 => array(
                    'title' => 'je'
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

QuizAnswer is here but i don't know how to retrieve the value, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

you can access your answer like this

```
*<?php
$data['Task'] = array(
    'type' => '1',
    'level' => '1',
    'date_availability' => array(
        'day' => '17',
        'month' => '08',
        'year' => '2012',
        'hour' => '00',
        'min' => '00'
    ),
    'date_end_availability' => array(
        'day' => '18',
        'month' => '08',
        'year' => '2012',
        'hour' => '00',
        'min' => '00'
    ),
    'date_accomplishment' => array(
        'day' => '18',
        'month' => '08',
        'year' => '2012',
        'hour' => '00',
        'min' => '00'
    ),
    'title' => 'ju',
    'description' => 'ji',
    'QuizQuestion' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'title' => 'jo',
            'QuizAnswer' => array(
                (int) 0 => array(
                    'title' => 'je'
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
;

echo $data['Task']['QuizQuestion'][0]['QuizAnswer'][0]['title'];


?>*
```

you can place it like this in your code to access it

$this->request->data['Task']['QuizQuestion'][0]['QuizAnswer'][0]['title'];

Comment: Let me know if any difficulty !

Comment: Thank you for your answer !
but  is there an other way to retrieve the data and intert it in the db automatically ? because Quizanswer have a foreign key of QuizQuestion .

Comment: i wanted but i can't , i need 15 reputation to vote up , sorry (when i'll get enough i'll be back )